# Expressjs module bodyparser returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am playing around with a  simple html form, trying to parse the form data. Unfortunately My routes section only returns an undefined from my form elements

My app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var busboy = require('connect-busboy');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
module.exports = app;
```

Jade form,

```
form(method='post', action='/contact', enctype="multipart/form-data")
    .form-group
        label Name:
        input.form-control(name='name', type='text')
    input.btn.btn-default(name='submit',type='submit',value='Save')
```

My route,

```
router.post('/contact', function(req, res, next) {
    var name = req.body.name;

    console.log(req.body.name);

    res.redirect('google.com');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form has `multipart/form-data` enctype:

```
form(method='post', action='/contact', enctype="multipart/form-data")
```

But as it is written [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#errors), `body-parser` doesn`t handle such type of bodies:

> > This does not handle multipart bodies, due to their complex and typically large nature. For multipart bodies, you may be interested in
> >     the following modules:

Or you should change the middleware to parse body, or your form `enctype`.

Comment: So is there an enctype I can use with body-parser?